# Get difference between day just when the difference is positive

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp

Using Postgresql, I need to substract  two dates and to show the result just when the result of the difference between dates is positive or 0. In order to substract the dates I am using this:

```
SELECT
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ('2019-02-11 17:59:01.953894'::timestamp - '2019-12-09 02:08:16.01493'::timestamp))/60
```

However, I would need something like this:

```
SELECT
    DECODE(SIGN(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ('2019-02-11 17:59:01.953894'::timestamp - '2019-12-09 02:08:16.01493'::timestamp))/60 as d),-1, None,
                                                                                                                                ,1, d)
```

Running the previous query, I am getting an error in the following:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
LINE 2: ...mestamp - '2019-12-09 02:08:16.01493'::timestamp))/60 as df)
                                                                 ^
```

Do you have an idea how to get over this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `GREATEST` to turn negative values to 0:

```
GREATEST(
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (ts1 - ts2))/60,
    0
)
```

Or, if you want a `null` result when the difference is negative, you can use a `case` expression that compares the timestamps before attempting to substract them:

```
CASE WHEN ts1 > ts2 THEN  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (ts1 - ts2))/60 END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  SELECT greatest((EXTRACT(epoch from age('2019-02-11', now())) / 86400)::int, 0)
```